# Draw canvas in SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I just want to draw on a SurfaceView and have modified some sample code from [here](http://android-coding.blogspot.co.at/2011/05/drawing-on-surfaceview.html)

If I draw directly in the loop it works, but when I invoke the draw method It does not work. Any Ideas what thre problem could be?
But this is what I saw in other Tutorials, so it should work.
Sure I could use draw1. But I want to know why onDraw does not work here?

```
public class TestSurefaceView extends Activity {
MySurfaceView mySurfaceView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mySurfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mySurfaceView);
}
class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
    Thread thread = null;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    volatile boolean running = false;
    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Random random;
    public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        random = new Random();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running){
            if(surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
                Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                //draw(canvas); // does not work
                draw1(canvas); // works
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
    private void draw1(Canvas canvas){
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        int w = canvas.getWidth();int h = canvas.getHeight();
        int x = random.nextInt(w-1);
        int y = random.nextInt(h-1);
        int r = random.nextInt(255);
        int g = random.nextInt(255);
        int b = random.nextInt(255);
        paint.setColor(0xff000000 + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b);
        canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        draw1(canvas);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're missing your `setWillNotDraw(false);` call somewhere....

Answer (score 0):

SurfaceViews have two parts, the Surface and the View.  `onDraw()` is for drawing on the View.  The point of the Surface is that it's a separate layer, below the View UI layer, so you can draw on it without interfering with the usual View invalidate/redraw cycle.

It's hard to say why it "doesn't work" when you haven't explained what it is that doesn't happen.  One common problem when defining an `onDraw()` method is that, if the View UI gets an invalidate, it will call the method to draw on the View.  Because the View is on top of the Surface, anything drawn on the View will obscure the Surface, so e.g. an opaque background will prevent anything that happens on the Surface from being visible.

I generally recommend that you don't subclass SurfaceView, as there's no value in doing so, and good OOP practices encourage composition over inheritance.